# SQL Server 2005 query to find the records inserted within 5 hours

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a `varchar` column `mytime` where I use to store only time

Now I want to find out all the records which have inserted within 5 hours.

e.g.

```
Select *
from mytable
where **mytime + interval '5' hour > current_Time**
```

Comment: Your column stores only time? What is the date portion? Do you need to distinguish rows inserted in this 5 hour window today from rows inserted in that same 5 hour window yesterday, last Tuesday, or January 10th? How will you do that?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Note the username.

Comment: Might I suggest using the `datetime` data type to store your timestamp in? Best to use data types that are designed to hold the data you're looking to store. Then you can go crazy with the date functions to get what you're looking for.

Comment: @DanAndrews I don't know, I come across the occasional expert who you might think he/she knows what they're doing, and then they start talking... :-)

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. @AaronBertrand this particular table hold the record of today only so I need to check only on the time.

Comment: Ok, now why is it a `varchar` column?

Comment: @Beginner Please save your self some grief.  Make the column a datetime field.  You're over thinking the problem and losing functionality by storing just the time as a varchar.  You will look back at this someday and say, "what was I thinking!".  I speak from experience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since implicit conversion to datetime could fail if someone stuffed `'floob'` or `'32:45'` in the column - which they could because, you know, it's the wrong data type - you need to handle that case and deal with any bad data that has crept in there. You also need to normalize the time values to the same date, since time without date will have a date component of `1900-01-01` but anything involving adding/subtracting hours from `GETDATE()` will have a date component of today's date. So you will need something like this to handle all of that (and this assumes that your time is stored as simply `12:32` and not `12:32.000` or includes `AM`/`PM`):

```
-- first, get a variable to hold 5 hours ago on 1900-01-01:

DECLARE @cutoff DATETIME;
SET @cutoff = DATEADD(DAY,-DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETDATE()),DATEADD(HOUR,-5,GETDATE()));

-- now use that in the WHERE clause
-- and also check that the value can be converted
-- to a date and it is in hh:mm format.

-- need CASE expression here because you can't
-- control the order in which WHERE clauses are
-- evaluated by SQL Server.

SELECT ... WHERE
CASE 
  WHEN ISDATE(MyTime) = 1 
  AND MyTime LIKE '[ 0-2][0-6]:[0-6][0-9]'
THEN CONVERT(DATETIME, MyTime) END > @cutoff;
```

In SQL Server 2008 and above, you can use the `TIME` datatype, so you won't need to worry about coalescing the date. And in SQL Server 2012 and above, you can use `TRY_CONVERT` to avoid all that messy `CASE` logic.

The real answer: **fix the column and use the proper data type**. There is absolutely no reason to store time data in a string column. Then you can say:

```
WHERE MyTime > @cutoff;
```

And in this case you might actually stand some chance of seeking on an index rather than scanning the entire table.

Comment: +1, for "the real answer".  You can hack this together if you really want but you will regret it.